How to align the camera precisely to an image plane
I have an image plane and a camera of the exact same dimensions. I would like to precisely align the edges of the camera view to the edges of the plane.


How do I do this?

did u try track to constraint on camera?

@Chris hi thanks for the reply. How do I track to constraint?

I assume you added your image using the built-in addon Images as Planes. Make sure 3D cursor is at World Origin using Ctrl+C then import image and don't move or change the dimension for testing. Make sure it is on the XY plane.

Then make sure the image is selected and execute the following python script. This will create a camera and perfectly align it with the image.

import bpy
from mathutils import Euler

image_obj = bpy.context.active_object
mat = image_obj.material_slots[0].material

image = mat.node_tree.nodes["Image Texture"].image
RESOLUTION_X = image.size[0]
RESOLUTION_Y = image.size[1]

offset = 0
image_obj.location = (0, 0, 0 + offset)

bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
cam = bpy.context.active_object
cam.name = "temp_camera"
cam.rotation_euler = Euler((0, 0, 0), 'XYZ')
cam.data.type = 'ORTHO'

camera_distance = 2
scale_x = image_obj.dimensions[0] / 2 * camera_distance
scale_y = image_obj.dimensions[1] / 2 * camera_distance
cam.data.ortho_scale = max(scale_x, scale_y)

cam.location = (0, 0, camera_distance + offset)

bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = RESOLUTION_X
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = RESOLUTION_Y
bpy.context.scene.camera = cam


Fantastic! Thank you.
